# C# : How to sign in and keep it valid and make another webrequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = textBox1.Text;
    string password = textBox2.Text;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.youmint.com/LoginVerification.php?name="+userName+"&pass="+password+"&agreement=true&checkvalue=true");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    if (responseFromServer.Equals(""))
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in!!");
    else if (responseFromServer.Equals("1"))
        MessageBox.Show("Login failed!");
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.youmint.com/FreeSms.html");
    response = request.GetResponse();
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    /*secret code :P */
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
 }
```

So, that's my code... The first webrequest logs into the website. It works fine in the browser and returns 1 if the login is not correct. Then the second one is a normal webrequest to a webpage of the same website. But the login is already gone and the response I get is what I get if I'm not logged in! Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? How do I keep it alive? Do I have to use an invisible webbroswer control or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@liho1eye is correct. Here's some more info from the HttpWebRequest page:

> For security reasons, cookies are
>   disabled by default. If you want to
>   use cookies, use the CookieContainer
>   property to enable cookies.

You'll need to reference the HttpWebResponse.Cookies property to get the initial session token cookie.

Edit:

Here's a quick and dirty sample of making a request to a page, and transferring response cookies to the next request. Didn't do much testing or validation (so beware!) - just to give you the idea of the approach.

```
        //this only has login/password info, you may need other parameters to trigger the appropriate action:
        const string Parameters = "Login1$username=pfadmin&Login1$Password=password";

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://[WebApp]/Login.aspx");

        req.Method = "GET";
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        //Create POST request and transfer session cookies from initial request
        req = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/AdminWeb/Login.aspx");
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (Cookie c in resp.Cookies)
        {
            req.CookieContainer.Add(c);
        }
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //...continue on with your form POST
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!! I enabled the cookies but still I can't get it to work... What might be the problem? Please can you help me with some code, please... Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't just give you a general code snippet that will work, because your interaction with the server will depend on how the server handles the request. For instance, you are hitting a PHP page, which may allow the login/password parameters to be passed in a querystring as a GET request. In an ASP.Net page, if the login code is triggered by a button click event handler, you may need to make a GET request and parse the VIEWSTATE element, then send appropriate parameters as a POST to make sure the page is a postback and triggers the proper vent. You can see it gets very specific...

Comment: OH MY DEAR GOD! I LOVE YOU! IT WORKS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! *HUG HUG HUG*

Comment: The only thing I needed was the cookies, so I used that part of your code and it works!

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with "keep alive". 
You need to preserve session cookie between requests. For that you first need to enable cookies for your login request (read `HttpWebRequest` docs - it is a bit unobvious). Then you need to pass that cookie with all the following reuests.

Also please make use of the `using()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! So I tried using CookieContainer like this:
`request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();`
But it still doesn't work... Please, can you help me?
I saw that there is only one cookie instead of 3 when I visit via a web browser. BTW, tell me what the `using()` is :)
Thanks again!!!

Comment: That simply enables cookies for your request. You need to pass along the contents of the CookieContainer of the first response with each new request. mtazva showed you an example of how to do it. The using() is a C# statement that automagically disposes given object at the end of its scope. Read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx . As a rule of the thumb every object you instantiate that implements IDisposable should always be wrapped in using() statement.